# Plotly chart not updating with date slider input in r shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I'm not getting any error message, so I'm kind of stuck here. Everything seems to be working fine, but when I move the slider widget in the app, the dates don't update on the plotly graph. Something tells me I'm missing something in my ggplot (related to xlim?) but everything I try breaks the app. I've attached the code below, as well as a sample of my dataset.

```
rm(list=ls())

#Libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library (plotly)
library(shinythemes)

#Load Data
data<-read_excel("C:/Users/Kanew/OneDrive/Desktop/RApp/Unemployment2.xlsx")
data$Date<-as.Date(data$Date)


ui<-fluidPage(
    
    theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
    
    tabsetPanel(
        
        tabPanel("Welcome",
                 
                 HTML(paste(
                     
                     h1("Welcome!"),
                     
                     p("Welcome to the Unemployment Exploration Application. In this application you will find tabs,
                            located at the top of your screen, for data visualization and data table exploration."), '<br/>',
                     
                     p("The data visualization tab includes functionality to visualize the unemployment rate by various 
                            racial/ethnic categories of your choice. The graph includes functions for magnification, panning, 
                            and observing individual data points at your choice (by hovering over data points)."), '<br/>',
                     
                     p(" The data table tab is a searchable data table that allows you to search the dataset and download the 
                             dataset if you'd like."),'<br/>',
                     
                     p("Enjoy!")))),
        
        
        tabPanel("Data Visualization",
                 
                sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        sliderInput(inputId = "Date",
                                    label = "Dates:",
                                    min = as.Date("2010-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                                    max = as.Date("2021-02-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                                    value = as.Date("2010-01-01"), timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d",
                                    step = 1, animate = animationOptions(interval = 1800))),
                    
                mainPanel(h1("National Unemployment Rate by Racial/Ethnic Category"),
                           plotlyOutput("plot", height = 'auto', width = 'auto'),
                              
                              
                            selectInput(
                                inputId = "Category",
                                label = "Select Race or National Rate",
                                choices = c("All",unique(data$Category)),
                                selected = "All")))),

        
        tabPanel("Data Table",
                 
                 h1("Data Table"),
                 
                 DT::dataTableOutput("data"))
        
        
    ))

server<-function(input, output){
    
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        data %>%
            filter(Category == input$Category | input$Category == "All" | Date == input$Date) %>%
            ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x=Date, y = Rate, colour = Category)) +
            geom_line() + 
            xlab("Year") + ylab("Unemployment Rate (%)") +
            scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18))+
            scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years" , date_labels = "%Y")+
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
            theme_economist() +
            scale_fill_economist()})
    
    
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(data)})
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```
> head(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Date       Category  Rate
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
1 2010-01-01 National   9.8
2 2010-02-01 National   9.8
3 2010-03-01 National   9.9
4 2010-04-01 National   9.9
5 2010-05-01 National   9.6
6 2010-06-01 National   9.4
> head(data, 20)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   Date       Category  Rate
   <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
 1 2010-01-01 National   9.8
 2 2010-02-01 National   9.8
 3 2010-03-01 National   9.9
 4 2010-04-01 National   9.9
 5 2010-05-01 National   9.6
 6 2010-06-01 National   9.4
 7 2010-07-01 National   9.4
 8 2010-08-01 National   9.5
 9 2010-09-01 National   9.5
10 2010-10-01 National   9.4
11 2010-11-01 National   9.8
12 2010-12-01 National   9.3
13 2011-01-01 National   9.1
14 2011-02-01 National   9  
15 2011-03-01 National   9  
16 2011-04-01 National   9.1
17 2011-05-01 National   9  
18 2011-06-01 National   9.1
19 2011-07-01 National   9  
20 2011-08-01 National   9
```

Updated code per ismirsehregal's solution:

```
rm(list=ls())

#Libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library (plotly)
library(shinythemes)

#Load Data
data<-read_excel("C:/Users/Kanew/OneDrive/Desktop/RApp/Unemployment2.xlsx")
uniqueCats <- unique(data$Category)
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)



ui<-fluidPage(
    
    theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
    
    tabsetPanel(
        
        tabPanel("Welcome",
                 
                 HTML(paste(
                     
                     h1("Welcome!"),
                     
                     p("Welcome to the Unemployment Exploration Application. In this application you will find tabs,
                            located at the top of your screen, for data visualization and data table exploration."), '<br/>',
                     
                     p("The data visualization tab includes functionality to visualize the unemployment rate by various 
                            racial/ethnic categories of your choice. The graph includes functions for magnification, panning, 
                            and observing individual data points at your choice (by hovering over data points)."), '<br/>',
                     
                     p(" The data table tab is a searchable data table that allows you to search the dataset and download the 
                             dataset if you'd like."),'<br/>',
                     
                     p("Enjoy!")))),
        
        
        tabPanel("Data Visualization",
                 
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         sliderInput(inputId = "Date",
                                     label = "Dates:",
                                     min = min(data$Date),
                                     max = max(data$Date),
                                     value = min(data$Date),
                                     timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d",
                                     step = 1,
                                     animate = animationOptions(interval = 300))),
                     
                     mainPanel(h1("National Unemployment Rate by Racial/Ethnic Category"),
                               plotlyOutput("plot", height = 'auto', width = 'auto'),
                               
                               
                               selectInput(
                                   inputId = "Category",
                                   label = "Select Race or National Rate",
                                   choices = c("All", unique(data$Category)),
                                   selected = "All")))),
        
        
        tabPanel("Data Table",
                 
                 h1("Data Table"),
                 
                 DT::dataTableOutput("myDataTable"))
        
        
    ))

server<-function(input, output){
    
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        
        if(input$Category == "All"){
            catFilter<-uniqueCats
        } else{
            catFilter<-input$Category
        }
        
        filteredData <- filter(data, Category %in% catFilter & Date <= input$Date)
        req(nrow(filteredData) > 0)
        
        myGGPlot <- ggplot(filteredData, mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Rate, colour = Category),
                        geom_line() +
                        geom_point() +
                        xlab("Year") + ylab("Unemployment Rate (%)") +
                        scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18))+
                        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years" , date_labels = "%Y")+
                        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
                        theme_economist()+
                        scale_fill_economist(),
                        
                        ggplotly(myGGPlot))
                        
                        })
        
    
    
    output$myDataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(data)
        })
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Good questions - I want the option to choose what series to chart, but also the option to chart all series at once. I.e. all different types of unemployment vs some other single type (having trouble with checkboxes right now, but I'll work on that later). Regarding the dates on the x-axis, it's a time-series graph. So the idea is that users have the option to view 2010-2011, or 2010-2015, etc.

Comment: Please use the output of `dput(head(data, 20))` to share your data.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Sorry for the delay! The app runs, but there is nothing graphed on the plotly output in the data visualization tab? I updated the question with the revised code

Comment: I added a picture to my answer. The output is fine. You need to use the slider to add more points to the graph.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going wrong in your above code.

First of all `renderPlotly` expects a plotly-object. Accordingly you need `ggplotly` to convert your ggplot to a plotly object.

Furthermore, your filter statements were faulty.

Please check the following:

```
#Libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
# library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library(plotly)
library(shinythemes)

#Load Data
# myData <- read_excel("C:/Users/Kanew/OneDrive/Desktop/RApp/Unemployment2.xlsx")
myData <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Date = c("2010-01-01","2010-02-01",
           "2010-03-01","2010-04-01","2010-05-01","2010-06-01",
           "2010-07-01","2010-08-01","2010-09-01","2010-10-01",
           "2010-11-01","2010-12-01","2011-01-01","2011-02-01",
           "2011-03-01","2011-04-01","2011-05-01","2011-06-01",
           "2011-07-01","2011-08-01"),
  Category = c("National","National",
               "National","National","TestCategory","National","National",
               "National","National","National","National","National",
               "National","National","TestCategory","National","National",
               "National","TestCategory","National"),
  Rate = c(9.8,9.8,9.9,9.9,9.6,9.4,
           9.4,9.5,9.5,9.4,9.8,9.3,9.1,9,9,9.1,9,9.1,9,9)
)
uniqueCats <- unique(myData$Category)
myData$Date <- as.Date(myData$Date)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                tabsetPanel(
                  tabPanel("Welcome",
                           HTML(
                             paste(
                               h1("Welcome!"),
                               p(
                                 "Welcome to the Unemployment Exploration Application. In this application you will find tabs,
                            located at the top of your screen, for data visualization and data table exploration."
                               ),
                               '<br/>',
                               p(
                                 "The data visualization tab includes functionality to visualize the unemployment rate by various
                            racial/ethnic categories of your choice. The graph includes functions for magnification, panning,
                            and observing individual data points at your choice (by hovering over data points)."
                               ),
                               '<br/>',
                               p(
                                 " The data table tab is a searchable data table that allows you to search the dataset and download the
                             dataset if you'd like."
                               ),
                               '<br/>',
                               p("Enjoy!")
                             )
                           )),
                  tabPanel(
                    "Data Visualization",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        sliderInput(
                          inputId = "Date",
                          label = "Dates:",
                          min = min(myData$Date),
                          max = max(myData$Date),
                          value = min(myData$Date),
                          timeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d",
                          step = 1,
                          animate = animationOptions(interval = 300)
                        )
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        h1("National Unemployment Rate by Racial/Ethnic Category"),
                        plotlyOutput("plot"), # , height = 'auto', width = 'auto'
                        selectInput(
                          inputId = "Category",
                          label = "Select Race or National Rate",
                          choices = c("All", unique(myData$Category)),
                          selected = "All"
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Data Table",
                           h1("Data Table"),
                           DT::dataTableOutput("myDataTable"))
                ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    if(input$Category == "All"){
      catFilter <- uniqueCats
    } else {
      catFilter <- input$Category
    }

    filteredData <- filter(myData, Category %in% catFilter & Date <= input$Date)
    req(nrow(filteredData) > 0)
    
    myGGPlot <- ggplot(filteredData, mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Rate, colour = Category)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      xlab("Year") + ylab("Unemployment Rate (%)") +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18)) +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years" , date_labels = "%Y") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
      theme_economist() +
      scale_fill_economist()
    
      ggplotly(myGGPlot)
  })
  
  output$myDataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]